# How to pass the URL as a parameter to a JMeter Load Test execution in Azure DevOps?

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops

Azure DevOps offers us the possibility of running Load Tests in the Cloud. Thus, we can use multiple servers to hit the web app under test from different locations.

The Azure DevOps UI allows us to upload a JMeter test file, plus some supporting files, like  CSV files that will be used by the test.

When we develop the test, we'll most certainly be running JMeter against a locally running application, to make sure our requests are properly formatted and are hitting the application as desired. Thus, we'll be running JMeter locally against localhost:.

When we upload the test plan file to Azure DevOps, we'll expect the test to run against the application that is deployed to Azure App Services (for example). Hard-coding the URL in the test plan is quite inconvenient. Isn't there a way to make Azure DevOps pass this a parameter to JMeter before the load test runs?

JMeter accepts variables to be defined in the local environment, outside of the test plan, but the Load Test UI in Azure DevOps doesn't seem to support this.

Comment: Hey Gabriel. I don't think dynamically & automatically you can pass the URL to the test plan after the App is deployed. Based on my experience with AWS, I am sure there is a possibility to get the URL/IP address where the application gets dynamically deployed using some API. Probably you can include that request as part of JMeter test plan and correlate its response to feed it into subsequent requests. However, if we are looking at static IPs, am wondering why you would not want to pass them as yet another supporting file after parameterizing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Azure DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=vsts) it is possible to provide "Supporting Files"

[image]

So you can put your URL(s) into i.e. CSV file and load it inside your JMeter test using one of the following approaches:

- [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)
- [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)
- [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)